# How to turn value in timestamp column into numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, timestamp

I have a dataframe:

```
id          timestamp
1           "2025-08-02 19:08:59"
1           "2025-08-02 19:08:59"
1           "2025-08-02 19:09:59"
```

I need to turn timestamp into integer number to iterate over conditions. So it look like this:

```
id          timestamp
1           20250802190859
1           20250802190859
1           20250802190959
```

Comment: @thepunitsingh it was easier

Comment: check if your column `timestamp` is datetime64. Then use `df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`

Answer (score 1):

you can convert string using string of pandas :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1],'timestamp':["2025-08-02 19:08:59",
"2025-08-02 19:08:59",
"2025-08-02 19:09:59"]})
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].str.replace(r'[-\s:]', '').astype('float64')
>>> df
  id          timestamp
0   1 20250802190859.000
1   1 20250802190859.000
2   1 20250802190959.000
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: i copied your example... please give us a normal input, take these questions seriously

Comment: if your tiype is datetime do this:  `pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solutions provided in this post: [How to turn timestamp into float number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383819/how-to-turn-timestamp-into-float-number) and loop through the dataframe.

Let's say you have already imported `pandas` and have a dataframe `df`, see the additional code below:

```
import re
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df1 = df.copy()
for x in range(len(df[0])):
    df1[0][x] = re.sub(r'\D','', df[0][x])
```

This way you will not modify the original dataframe `df` and will get desired output in a new dataframe `df1`.

Full code that I tried (including creatiion of first dataframe), this might help in removing any confusions:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
l = ["2025-08-02 19:08:59", "2025-08-02 19:08:59", "2025-08-02 19:09:59"]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df1 = df.copy()
for x in range(len(df[0])):
    df1[0][x] = re.sub(r'\D','', df[0][x])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the file, skipping the first line (or better: validating that it contains the header fields as expected) and for each line, splitting it at the first space/tab/whitespace. The second part, e.g. `"2025-08-02 19:08:59"`, can be parsed using [`datetime.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=date#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat). You can then turn the `datetime` object back to a string using [`datetime.strftime(format)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=date#datetime.date.strftime) with e.g. `format = '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`. Note that there is no "milliseconds" format in strftime though. You could use `%f` for microseconds.

Note: if `datetime.fromisoformat()` fails to parse the dates, try [`datetime.strptime(date_string, format)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=date#datetime.datetime.strptime) with a different `format`,  e.g. `format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`.